# How to keep checkbox checked when you click back and filters still working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these checkboxes

```
<div class="col-6 col-md-3 checkbox-rounds" id="filter-checks">
  <p class="orange OldStandard"> Menu Filters</p>
  <a type="button" class="check orange pointer OldStandard">Select All </a>
  <br>
  <a type="button" class="uncheck orange pointer OldStandard"> Unselect All</a>
  <br>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="vegan" id="vegan"/><label for="vegan" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Vegan</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="vegetarian" id="vegetarian"/> <label for="vegetarian" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Vegetarian</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="pescetarian" id="pescetarian"/> <label for="pescetarian" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Pescetarian</label>
         <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="dairy-free" id="dairy-free"/> <label for="dairy-free" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Dairy-free</label>
         <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="egg-free" id="egg-free"/> <label for="egg-free" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Egg-free</label>
         <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="fish-free" id="fish-free"/> <label for="fish-free" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Fish-free</label>
         <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="shellfish" id="shellfish"/> <label for="shellfish" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span> Shellfish-free</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="tree" id="tree"/> <label for="tree" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Tree nut-free</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="peanut" id="peanut"/> <label for="peanut" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Peanut-free</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="soy" id="soy"/> <label for="soy" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span> Soy-free</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="total-fat" id="total-fat"/> <label for="total-fat" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span> Low Total Fat</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="saturated-fat" id="saturated-fat"/> <label for="saturated-fat" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Low Saturated Fat</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="cholesterol" id="cholesterol"/> <label for="cholesterol" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Low Cholesterol</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="sodium" id="sodium"/> <label for="sodium" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Low Sodium</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="protein" id="protein" /> <label for="protein" class="OldStandard"> <span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Protein &#62;25g</label>
          <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-round" value="calories" id="calories" /> <label for="calories" class="OldStandard"><span><i class="fa fa-circle"></i><i class="fa fa-check" ></i></span>Calories  &#60;450 calories</label>
        <br>

  </div>
```

If a user checks one the meals get filter, and they can chose a meal it will take them to another page, but if they click back through the browser or the back button, how do I keep the checkboxes that they filtered still there? Here is my javascript:

```
$(function() {
      $("#filter-checks :checkbox").click(function() {
        $(".deliveryItem").hide();
        var selector = '.deliveryItem';
        $("#filter-checks :checkbox:checked").each(function(e,i) {
          selector += '.' + i.value;
        });
        $(selector).show();
      });
    });
```

I tried this for the back button, but now everything becomes checked when I go back and nothing is filtered

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
  $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true)
```

};

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true) that makes all checkboxes checked. Read about session data between pages. Is this SPA?

Comment: You can have an array/object storing references to checkboxes checked and than [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) that array/object into [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)/[`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to retrieve it.

Comment: Yes but my checkboxes are not inside a form so how can I store them inside sessions?

Comment: You can put it into the history pushstate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every click on checkbox store the `id` of the selected checkbox in a variable `_checked`

```
var _checked="";
$(function() {
  init();
  $("#filter-checks :checkbox").click(function() {
    $(".deliveryItem").hide();
    if($(this).is(":checked")) _checked+=this.id+',';
    else _checked=_checked.replace(this.id+',','');

    var selector = '.deliveryItem';
    $("#filter-checks :checkbox:checked").each(function(e, i) {
      selector += '.' + i.value;
    });
    $(selector).show();
  });
});
```

> The localStorage property allows you to access a local Storage object.
>   localStorage is similar to sessionStorage. The only difference is
>   that, while data stored in localStorage has no expiration time, data
>   stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the browsing session
>   ends—that is, when the browser is closed.
>
> It should be noted that data stored in either localStorage or
>   sessionStorage is specific to the protocol of the page.

You can use **[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** to store your selection `onbeforeunload`

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if(_checked!="") localStorage.setItem('selection',_checked);
};
```

`onload` call the init method to read the selection from the localStorage and check them

```
function init(){

    _checked = localStorage.getItem('selection',_checked);

    if(_checked) {
        var ch = _checked.split(',');
        ch.forEach(function(val){
             $('#'+val).prop('checked', true);
        });


        // Your Filter Action
        $(".deliveryItem").hide();

        var selector = '.deliveryItem';
        $("#filter-checks :checkbox:checked").each(function(e, i) {
             selector += '.' + i.value;
        });

       $(selector).show();
    }
}
```

**Full JS**

CHECK THE SNIPPET https://jsfiddle.net/ejvf13b0/1/

```
var _checked="";
$(function() {
  init();
  $("#filter-checks :checkbox").click(function() {
    $(".deliveryItem").hide();
    if($(this).is(":checked")) _checked+=this.id+',';
    else _checked=_checked.replace(this.id+',','');

    var selector = '.deliveryItem';
    $("#filter-checks :checkbox:checked").each(function(e, i) {
      selector += '.' + i.value;
    });
    $(selector).show();
  });
});

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if(_checked!="") localStorage.setItem('selection',_checked);
};

function init(){

    _checked = localStorage.getItem('selection',_checked);

    if(_checked) {
        var ch = _checked.split(',');
        ch.forEach(function(val){
             $('#'+val).prop('checked', true);
        });


         // Your Filter Action
        $(".deliveryItem").hide();

        var selector = '.deliveryItem';
        $("#filter-checks :checkbox:checked").each(function(e, i) {
             selector += '.' + i.value;
        });

       $(selector).show();
    }
}
```

This approach will store the selection locally in the browser and selection will not be available across different browser.

It will be available in the current browser even if you come back to the website days later.

To clear the selection call `localStorage.clear();`

This will delete all data stored in local storage.

Comment: It stays chosen but now it doesn't filter the meals, it goes back to normal with the checkboxes checked. I have to click a filter for the others to activate again

Comment: you need to call your filter action inside `init` again on page load

Comment: where is your filter action?

Comment: I put it after the `if(_checked) {` statement is finished?

Comment: `$(function() {
      $("#filter-checks :checkbox").click(function() {
        $(".deliveryItem").hide();
        var selector = '.deliveryItem';
        $("#filter-checks :checkbox:checked").each(function(e,i) {
          selector += '.' + i.value;
        });
        $(selector).show();
      });
    });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145447/discussion-between-sarah-and-nadir-laskar).